# Is fgets more effective than scanf when comparing strings in C?

Tags: c, fgets, c-strings

When working on the following code:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGHT 256
int main(void)
{
   char name[MAX_NAME_LENGHT];
   printf("Enter your name: \n");
   scanf("%s", name);
   if(strncmp(name, "John Smith", 10) == 0)
   {
      printf("Hello, John Smith!\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Intruder!!!\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Many errors occur and despite inputing `John Smith` the output prints `Intruder!!!`. However, when I replace

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

with

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

the output prints `Hello, John Smith!` Why is this?

Comment: Well for one thing `scanf` with the `"%s"` format reads *space delimited words*.

Comment: Have you tried printing name before the strncmp just to check what was saved there?

Comment: There is no reason to use `strncmp` here. Use `strcmp` so you don't have to count characters in the match. And *always* check the return value of `scanf` (and, for that matter, `fgets`).

Comment: Your code with `fgets()` will also report "Hello, John Smith!" if you type "John Smithson" or "John Smithers" or anything else that starts `John Smith`.  You need to remove the newline retained by `fgets()`.  Note that when you type "John Smith" but read it with `scanf("%s", name)`, you only read the "John"; the blank and the "Smith" are still waiting to be read.

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: @rici I was recommended not to use strcmp because it is unsafe.

Comment: @user24741: Yes but if you type something longer than `John Smith` like `John Smither` it will just compare the `John Smith` part and it seems to be equal. Use `strcmp` and take care of your string before. Use `fgets` as I said in my comment below the answer. `fgets` appends an trailing `'\0'` so that it will be a valid C-string that `strcmp` will work with. Another possibility would be to use `strncmp` with the buffer size as it would stop earlier if a `'\0'` in one string is found.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank You, I was unaware of this.

Comment: `strcmp()` is for comparing _strings_.  There is nothing unsafe about `strcmp(string_a, string_b);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below line for your usage, so `scanf` keeps taking in values until it encounters a `'\n'` (newline), so spaces get saved as well.

```
scanf("%[^\n]", name);
```

Remember that `scanf` stands for "scan formatted" and there's precious little less formatted than user-entered data. It's ideal if you have total control of the input data format but generally unsuitable for user input.

Comment: I just want to metion that the use of `scanf` with `%s` can lead to a buffer overflow of `name` if the user inputs a lot of data because `name` is a variable on the stack here. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430310/8051589) for more explanation. So the use `fgets` should be the preffered way.

Comment: I think `fgets` and `scanf` return different strings as well (one includes carriage return, but I forget which)

Comment: That `%[^\n]s` is not valid. Should be `%[^\n]`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Strictly, the `%[^\n]s` is valid, but it isn't useful. It looks for a literal `s` after the newline has been found, and the match fails because an `s` is not a newline, but there's no way for `scanf()` to report that failure (so it doesn't). You're right — it isn't what is wanted; you're over-claiming to say it's invalid. (Consider: `"%23[^\ns]s"` — that looks for a sequence of up to 23 characters other than `s` or newline, followed by an `s` (and not a newline). There are still problems detecting whether the post-conversion match worked, but it is more nearly plausible.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree I worded my comment incorrectly. I meant "is not valid here" (and might cause issues). @RajatKothari please read the comment as - That `%[^\n]s` will not give correct results here. Should be `%[^\n]`.